# How to select multiple items in a list box on website with VBA?

Tags: html, vba, webautomation

I log into a website and I'm attempting to select all items in a list.

The login works, but the items are not being highlighted or selected prior to submitting.

```vb
Sub BrowseToSite() 'Login to site

    'set ie = internetexplorer for reference
    Dim ie As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim htmldoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim htmlinput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim htmlbuttons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim objIE As Object
      
    'see window and navigate to website (HOURLY VOLUME ENERGY COMPOSITION - HVEC)
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "www.website.com"
        
    'wait for brower to load
    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop
        
    'Enters username and password
    Set htmldoc = ie.document
    Set htmlinput = htmldoc.getElementById("USER")
    htmlinput.Value = "LoginUsername"
    Set htmlinput = htmldoc.getElementById("PASSWORD")
    htmlinput.Value = "Password1"
    
    'finds form > submit button (under class = "LoginSubmit")
    htmldoc.forms(0).submit
    
    'select all Locations
    ie.document.getElementsByName("ctl00$contentPlaceHolder$ctl00$availableLocations").Value = "1297"
    ie.document.getElementsByName("ctl00$contentPlaceHolder$ctl00$availableLocations").Value = "3216"
    ie.document.getElementsByName("ctl00$contentPlaceHolder$ctl00$availableLocations").Value = "3135"
    objIE.document.getElementsByName("ctl00$contentPlaceHolder$ctl00$availableLocations")(0).Click

End Sub
```

Here is the HTML Code:

```
<tr>
    <td class="fieldLabel">Location:</td>
    <td class="fieldData" colspan="3">
        
        
        <select size="12" name="ctl00$contentPlaceHolder$ctl00$availableLocations" multiple="multiple" id="contentPlaceHolder_ctl00_availableLocations" tabindex="8" class="fullWidth" onFocus="resetList(&#39;operatorList&#39;);">
<option value="1297">1297 - Test1</option>
<option value="3216">3216 - Test2</option>
<option value="3135">3135 - Test3</option>
```

Comment: For one, it looks like you are missing a `"` after `3135`.

Comment: Must have cut it off. Added back quote.

Comment: Also ?  `htmldoc.forms(0).submit21`  ?   You need to give time for the page to reload after logging in.   Since your select has an id you should use `getElementById` and that will return a single element, not a collection like `getElmentsByName`

Answer (score 0):

**Current code:**

By attempting to set the value of a collection (which is what `getElementsByName` returns) you should be getting an error telling you that `.value` is not available. It is a property of nodes within your collection and would require indexing into your collection. As you don't mention an error I have to wonder if in your actual code you are masking errors with an `On Error Resume Next`?

@TimWilliams makes an important point in the comment about leaving enough time for the webpage to update after actions like `.Submit, .Click, .Refresh`.

Also, use a proper page load wait of:

```
While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState<>4:DoEvents:Wend
```

You could update the loop syntax (I'm old!)

---

**What you can try:**

Assuming the parent `select` is multi-select enabled then I would gather a nodeList of all the options using `querySelectorAll` and loop that list setting `.Selected = True` on each node.

You can gather the nodeList by using the `id` of the parent `select` with `child combinator` and the `type` selector `option` for the children within

```
Dim nodes As Object, i As Long

Set nodes = htmlDoc.querySelectorAll("#contentPlaceHolder_ctl00_availableLocations > option")

For i  = 0 To nodes.Length - 1
    nodes.item(i).Selected = True
Next
```

---

This will allow you to select without having to specify each node by either its index in the select options list, or by using the value attribute value etc. E.g. Setting individually using value attribute would look like:

```
htmlDoc.querySelector("[value='1297']").Selected =True
```

etc...

---

Read about css selectors used by querySelectorAll here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors